# Design pattern for command line software with multiple functionalities

Tags: design-patterns

I'm developing a program that is going to be called from the command line. The software will be a sort of 'kit' with differing functionality based on the different flags defined while calling the program. Some of this functionality is wildly differing from others and the only similarity is the type of file that it operates on.

I was wondering what the best design pattern is to implement this kind of functionality? I've read about the facade design pattern which splits each module into a different sub-system. Building each piece of functionality under a different facade would keep it modular and would allow me to build a single class to handle which facade to call.

Is this the best way to go about it, or would you recommend something different?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: You have mentioned the different functionalities will be there based on the flag. So, your internal logic will change based on your context, correct? Please give some example of your functionalities that will change based on flag.

Comment: @Sam I am afraid you might receive downvotes, it is interesting but little more for Software Design, than this venue, especially because it would need more details to clarify your intent and your goal you want to achieve. This way you get what people like or imagine, not what you need...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because this is a command line application, I think the [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) could be useful for you. Personally, I believe this is a good way to structure console apps.

This is a possible implementation (in c#) to support multiple commands:

```cs
// The main class, the entry point to the program
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Processor();
        p.Process(args);
    }
}

/* The command processor class, its responsibility is to take its input parameters to create the command and execute it. */
public class Processor
{
    private CommandFactory _commandFactory;

    public Processor()
    {
        _commandFactory = new CommandFactory();
    }

    public void Process(string[] args)
    {
        var arguments = ParseArguments(args);
        var command = _commandFactory.CreateCommand(arguments);

        command.Execute();
    }

    private CommandArguments ParseArguments(string[] args)
    {
        return new CommandArguments
        {
            CommandName = args[0]
        };        
    }
}

/* Creates a command based on command name */
public class CommandFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ICommand> _availableCommands = new ICommand[]
                    {
                        new Command1(), new Command2(), .....
                    };

    public ICommand CreateCommand(CommandArguments commandArguments)
    {
        var result = _availableCommands.FirstOrDefault(cmd => cmd.CommandName == commandArguments.CommandName);
        var command = result ?? new NotFoundCommand { CommandName = commandArguments.CommandName };
        command.Arguments = commandArguments;

        return command;
    }
}

public interface ICommand
{
    string CommandName { get; }
    void Execute();
}

/* One of the commands that you want to execute, you can create n implementations of ICommand */
public class Command1 : ICommand
{
    public CommandArguments Arguments { get; set; }

    public string CommandName
    {
        get { return "c1"; }
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        // do whatever you want to do ...
        // you can use the Arguments
    }
}


/* Null object pattern for invalid parametters */
public class NotFoundCommand : ICommand
{
    public string CommandName { get; set; }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find command: " + CommandName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely what I was looking for. For anyone visiting this thread, https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command has a great further explanation on this design partner.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

> the strategy pattern (also known as the policy pattern) is a behavioral software design pattern that enables selecting an algorithm at runtime

Comment: It is a glorified basic interface pattern. All the code is nice when done like that, similar things sharing same parts or behavior keeping under a specific category or family with the shared interface. I think good answer... upvoted